# Why is the parent div not expanding to child divs?

Tags: css, html

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cXgk/3/) demonstrating my problem, the parent div called `.player` will not expand to the same height as the games list.

```
.player{
    width:471px; 
    height:auto; 
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px; 
    background-color: rgb(12, 167, 210);
}
```

I have looked through StackOverflow at similar questions and there are indications to `overflow:hidden`, `clear:both` etc, but nothing seems to be working so I have took them away to show my original code. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Do the child divs `float` inside the parent?

Comment: yes plase see the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add overflow:hidden to .player:

```
.player {
   width: 471px;
   height: auto;
   clear: both;
   margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
   background-color: rgb(12, 167, 210);
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

This happens because you're floating elements inside of .player and thus the container collapses. The overflow: hidden; is one of the solutions, you could also use pseudoelements:

```
.player:after {
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   clear:both;
   float: none;
}
```

or create a new ad-hoc element and place it at the bottom of .player

```
<div class="clear-floats"></div>

.clear-floats {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

Also, you need to remove the fixed height in the element inside:

```
.gamescontain {
    width: 237px;
    /* height: 400px; REMOVE THIS */
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: but overflow:hidden cuts off all the results after the GPG and MPG divs on the left

Comment: OMG! I have no idea why games contain is 400px high! I have been at this for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shold add overflow:hidden; to .player css class

```
.player{width:471px; height:auto; clear:both; margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px; background-color: rgb(12, 167, 210); overflow:hidden;}
```

and delete the height of .gamescontain

```
.gamescontain{width:237px;float:right; clear:both;}
```

Comment: but this cuts off all the results after the GPG and MPG divs on the left

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:hidden to .player:

```
.player {
   width: 471px;
   height: auto;
   clear: both;
   margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
   background-color: rgb(12, 167, 210);
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: but this cuts off all the results after the GPG and MPG divs on the left

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding `overflow:hidden` to .player class remove `clear:both` from .gamescontain:

```
.gamescontain{width:237px;height:400px;float:right;}
```